# Backing up shared database to drive where other users cannot delete

Tags: excel, vba, autosave

I have been trying to automatically back up a database, that is on a shared drive, to a different drive every time it is accessed. I put together this code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
 'Saves the current file to a backup folder and the default folder
 'Note that any backup is overwritten
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="\\pdc2cif004.onelondon.tfl.local\vdm3_data1$\IanMartin\Desktop\Backup Files\" & _
             ActiveWorkbook.Name
     ActiveWorkbook.Save
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 End Sub
```

This was placed in the worksheet as Before Save. The code works if I access the database, but it does not work if anyone else access the database.

I know other staff have accessed the databases, but no backup file was created in my folder. I am trying to create a backup that will be placed in a drive where the other staff cannot accidentally find it and delete it by mistake.

Comment: A "database"?  Or a "workbook"?

Comment: I'm guessing other users don't have access to save to your folder on that network drive...

Comment: If you're saving to "...IanMartin\Desktop\Backup Files\" - are the other people using the program also having access to this directory?

Comment: What's you code doing or not doing?  Try stepping through the code with F8 to see what's going on. More tips about [Debugging VBA here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and also , check out how to put together a **[mcve]**..

Comment: do you have roaming profiles in your network?...is that part of your own user account?  users arent going to have privileges to write to your profile folders

Comment: The database is on a shared drive (I:). All staff have their own profile stored on drive U: All computers are linked via ThinClient Modems. When I am online the VBA code works in sending the backup from Drive I; to where my profile is based on Drive U: I know other staff have accessed the databases, but no backup file was created in my folder. I am trying to find a way to create a backup that will be placed in a drive where the other staff cannot accidently find it and delete it by mistake.

Comment: Ctznkane525, I believe you may very well be right, as we have roaming profiles that we can access from different locations. I have been told that we have a sharepoint site, would using this be a better way to safeguard the databases not being accidentally deleted?

Comment: if 12 people have this work book open at the same time, then even in the ideal situation where all the users have access to the backup folder you're still going to be faced with the last person to save is the only backup you'll get... FYI: Office365 claims to have better multi-user controls kinda like google sheets.

Comment: As far as I am aware only one person at a time can access the database at a time. A message comes up that the database is locked by another user and you can only read the database. So a backup should be generated each time the database is closed. The corporation I work for hasn't provided Office365 as an option to choose. We are using Excel 2010, which isn't the most up to date version available.